# Firebase Authentication. request.auth is null upon page refresh

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Client side Firebase seems to believe i have an authenticated user when I refresh the page, but the firestore firebase rules imply i don't have an authenticated user.

I have a firebase application where the user logs in using email and password via `signInWithEmailAndPassword`. I have the persistence set to `browserLocalPersistence`. normally when a user logs in the method `onAuthStateChanged` is called with the authenticated user object, and the app functions properly. when the user refreshes the page my `onAuthStateChanged` method fires again with a non null user, but all firebase queries fail because of my security rules. what am i doing wrong there.

This is a reactjs app. Let me know if I can offer any other answers that might give you something to go off of.

my firebase rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if isAuthenticated();
    }
    function isAuthenticated() {
        return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
  
}
```

My login code:

```
setPersistence(sharedFirebaseAuth, browserLocalPersistence)
    .then(() => {
        signInWithEmailAndPassword(sharedFirebaseAuth, email, password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
            })
            .catch((error) => {
            });
})
```

My onAuthStateChanged code

```
onAuthStateChanged(sharedFirebaseAuth, (user) => {
  if(user){
    user.reload().then(()=>{
      requestDocs();
    });
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to implement an Auth provider in order for it to keep my user info.

new file AuthContext.tsx

```
import React from "react"
import { User } from "firebase/auth";

export const AuthContext = React.createContext<User | null>(null)
```

new file AuthProvider.tsx

```
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { User } from "firebase/auth";
import { sharedFirebaseAuth } from "../Utils/SharedFirebase";
import { AuthContext } from "./AuthContext";

export interface AuthProviderProps {
    children: JSX.Element;
}

export const AuthProvider: FC<AuthProviderProps> = ({ children }: AuthProviderProps) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = sharedFirebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged((firebaseUser) => {
      setUser(firebaseUser);
    });
    return unsubscribe
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={user}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

and then i updated my index.tsx like so

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { AuthProvider } from './provider/AuthProvider';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
      <App />
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

and then updated my app.tsx section where i was calling the onAuthStateChanged to the following

```
    const user = useContext(AuthContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(user){
            requestDocs();
        }
    },[user]);
```

upon refresh it seems to keep all of the necessary auth info to pull in documents.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget the comma between `read` and `write`, Should look like `allow read, write: if isAuthenticated();`

Comment: thanks i've updated the example above with the comma. that was me trying to simplify it for stack overflow. the issue still is present